# Bokeh: Reference Select Widget in CustomJS Callback

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, bokeh

I want to be able to reference 2 Select widgets (`select1.value` and `select2.value`) in the CustomJS callback, so I cannot use `cb_obj.value`.

```
select1 = Select(title="Level:", options=['All Levels', '1', '2', '3'], callback=callback)
```

First, I tried referencing its value directly within the callback:

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, ts=true_source), code="""
var f = select1.value
```

This resulted in error: select1 is not defined:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: select1 is not defined
    at eval (eval at get (bokeh-1.1.0.min.js:31), <anonymous>:9:11)
    at i.execute (bokeh-1.1.0.min.js:31)
    at e.change_input (bokeh-widgets-1.1.0.min.js:31)
    at e.change_input (bokeh-widgets-1.1.0.min.js:31)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (bokeh-widgets-1.1.0.min.js:31)
```

Then I tried passing `select1` to the args in the callback:

```
 callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, ts=true_source, select1=select1), code="""
    var f = select1.value
```

Because `select1`'s argument is `callback=callback`, if I define `select1` before I define `callback`, python is going to generate an error because `callback` was referenced before assignment. Vice versa if I define `callback` before the select widget.

So I tried this: defining `select1` twice

```
select1 = ... (without the callback argument)
callback = ...
select1 = ... (with the callback argument)
```

This finally generated the bokeh chart. But when I clicked on the select widget, there is no value.

```
var f=select1.value;
console.log('Select1 type ' + f.constructor.name.toLowerCase()); // string, as expected
console.log('Value ' + f); // outputs 'Value ', so f is nothing
console.log('Select1 options ' + select1.options); // Output is as expected
```

`select1.value` would be not empty if I provide a default value argument to `select1`:

```
select1 = Select(title="Level:", value='1', options=['All Levels', '1', '2', '3'], callback=callback)
```

But then, `select1.value` would remain '1' no matter what I change the actual value of the widget to. So the value is not updating at all.

I appreciate the help.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work. I used `js_on_change` instead of adding `callback` as a widget argument.

In the callback function, I passed the widget names as arguments.

1) Define select widgets, necessary to specify the default value

```
select1 = Select(title="Level:", value='All Levels', options=['All Levels', '1', '2', '3'])
select2 = Select(...)
```

2) Define callback, pass widgets explicitly as arguments

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, ts=true_source, select1=select1, select2=select2), code="""
f = select1.value
g = select2.value
"""
```

3) js_on_change

```
select1.js_on_change('value', callback)
```

Comment: individual `callback` properties on widgets will be removed in Bokeh 2.0. The `js_on_change` is a newer general mechanism that works for any property on any model, and should always be preferred at this point.